# How can i modify def __str__ so it returns a matrix without brackets [ ] and without ","

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here is my code, and I need my def **str** to print my marrix without the brackets [ ] and without the “,”

Here is what is returning:

```
[0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0]
```

And this is what i want it to return

```
0 0 0

0 0 0

0 0 0
```

```py
class Matrix():
    

    def __init__(self, width = int, height = int, fill_value=0):
        self.height = height
        self. width = width
        self.rows = [[fill_value] * width for _ in range (height)] #A for matrix A

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n" .join(map(str, self.rows))’’’
```

Sorry if I didn’t write my code perfectly im still figuring out how to use StackOverflow.

Comment: `return "\n".join(" ".join(map(str, row)) for row in rows)`

Comment: Or equivalently, `return "\n".join(map(lambda row: " ".join(map(str, row)),rows))` - but I think the first one is preferable.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I was for hours trying to figure it out!

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be `self.rows` rather than `rows`, but I guess you figured that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"\n".join([" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in self.rows])` to do it.

```
class Matrix():
    def __init__(self, width = 3, height = 3, fill_value=0):
        self.height = height
        self. width = width
        self.rows = [[fill_value] * width for _ in range (height)] #A for matrix A

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join([" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in self.rows])
```