# Printing out a matrix out of a two dimensional list

Tags: python

I would like to implement the **str** method to nicely format the string representation of the matrix: one line per row, two characters per number (%2d) and a space between numbers. For example:

```
m = Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])

print(m)

1  0  0

0  1  0

0  0  1
```

I've tried this:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.rows = rows
      


    def __str__(self):
        for element in self.rows:
            for i in element:
                print(i, end=" ")
            print()
```

But my output becomes

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6
 
7 8 9 

None
```

How would I solve this? Because the none shouldn't be there.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use numpy? This is basically what it was made for.

Comment: Note that `__str__` is expected to return the string representation of your object, _not_ print it out

Comment: yes, the idea was to figure out a solution without numpy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i modify def \_\_str\_\_ so it returns a matrix without brackets \[ \] and without ","](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884413/how-can-i-modify-def-str-so-it-returns-a-matrix-without-brackets-and-wit)

Answer (score 1):

The `__str__` method has to return a string, not print it.
What you are seeing is:

1. The prints inside of `__str__`.
2. The return value of `__str__`, which is `None`.

To correct it, build a string in `__str__` and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it like this?

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.rows = np.array(rows)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(np.array2string(row)[1:-1] for row in self.rows)

m = Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])

print(m)
```

Notice that we here convert rows to to a 2d numpy array first. If you want to avoid numpy for some reason, you can do this.

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.rows = rows
  
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.rows)
 
m = Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])

print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, rows):
        self.rows = rows

    def read(self):
        for element in self.rows:
            for i in element:
                print(i, end="  ")
            print('\n')


m = Matrix([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])

m.read()
```

You Should use something like this. Creating a new function to represent your data is good practice than trying to use the `__str__` method to do your job. because you might need to handle other edge cases explicitly

---

Output:

```
1  0  0  

0  1  0  

0  0  1
```

---

**Note**: This way you can remove **None** at the end as well

because The first is inside function and the second is outside function. When a function doesn't return anything, it implicitly returns None.